# AuditIgnore on some functions

Tags: asp.net-core, audit.net

On application first startup I have a seed function called.
I am using audit.net to audit EF entities.
Is there any way not to audit the seeded data on startup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a [Global Switch Off](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#global-switch-off), for example:

```cs
Audit.Core.Configuration.AuditDisabled = true;
Seed();
Audit.Core.Configuration.AuditDisabled = false;
```